# Generalized notion of independence

Tags: linear-algebra

The set of points $\mathbb{v}_i, i \in [1,n]$, in a vector space $V$ is called independent if for any $\mathbb{a}=(a_1,\dotsc,a_n)\neq 0$ $\sum_i a_i \mathbb{v}_i \neq 0$. One can add an extra constraint to $\mathbb{a}$, e.g. we need $\mathbb{a}\neq 0, |\mathbb{a}|_{0}\leq k$, i.e. at most $k$ elements of $\mathbb{a}$ are non-zero. This gives a weaker *k-independence* property: $\mathbb{v}_i, i \in [1,n]$ are k-independent if any $k$ of them are independent. Clearly, n-independent set is independent.

What is a proper term for *k-independence* property?

Answer (score 1):

I think for the case of "at most k" it's simply the rank of the corresponding matrix. Of course, the rank equal k does not guarantee that *any* k-subset is linear independent. What can one say of a set of n elements which are "k-wise linear independent"? The set of all k-wise linear independent elements, or [k-frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-frame) (particularly the set of orthonormal k-frames) is known as the Stiefel manifold. Now, ["every orthogonal transformation of a k-frame ... results in another k-frame, and any two k-frames are related by some orthogonal transformation."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel_manifold). Therefore, our set (when orthonormalized) is simply a number of rotations of one k-frame. Fundamental characteristic of our set remains k, the rank.